# How to convert this text into probabilities?

Tags: probability

[image]

How do we convert the table into probabilities?
Let $S=\text{patient survives}$, $J=\text{patient is junior}$, $Sr=\text{patient is senior}$. Can we say that $P(S|J,T_2)=0.5$, or $P(S|Sr,T_2)=0.35$?

The problem is that the sol.manual states that $P(S|J,T_2)=24/40=0.6$

Comment: I think so, presumably the rates are just percentages.

Comment: @Ian the thing is the solution manual states that $P(S|J,T_1)=16/40$... I have no idea how to get this

Comment: @Ian sorry, I meant another prob. I've edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, it's really not entirely clear from the context what each entry of the table should mean.